# Spring boot restful service Post request always returns null as response message in test code using Junit

Tags: rest, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit

This is a demo controller.

```
@PostMapping("/rest/new")
    public ResponseEntity<MessageDto> newUser(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageDto().setMessage(userService.createUser(userDto)));
    }
```

This is service layer.

```
 @Override
    public String createUser(UserDto userDto) {
//        Do Something
        return "Successful!!";
    }
```

This is the test code to test the controller

```
@Test
    public void testPostRestController() throws Exception {
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        userDto.setName("AA");
        userDto.setEmail("a@a.a");
        userDto.setId((long) 1);

        when(userService.createUser(userDto)).thenReturn("Successful!!");
        mockMvc.perform(post("/rest/new")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
                    .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(userDto)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.message", is(userService.createUser(userDto))))
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
    }
```

The problem is when I run the test code, it is supposed to check the response status and response message. The response status matched but the problem is the response message always returns as null.

error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.message"
Expected: is "Successful!!"
     but: was null
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
when(userService.createUser(any(UserDto.class))).thenReturn("Successful!!");
```

Instead of

```
when(userService.createUser(userDto)).thenReturn("Successful!!");
```

This should ideally fix the NPE

Comment: But it requires a cast which got error in run-time.